# WordPress Tag Cloud Filter Prevents Widget HTML from loading

Tags: filters, widgets, tags

I have a sidebar in wordpress registered like this:

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Blog Sidebar',
    'id'            => 'blog_sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-wrapper col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

Then, I'm dropping the tag cloud widget in there. It produces the widget code with title wrapped in `<h2>` and widget code wrapped in a `<div>` with classes above. So far, so good.

Now, I need to make some changes to how tag cloud is displayed, so I add a filter like so:

```
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args','set_tag_cloud_features');
  function set_tag_cloud_features($args) {
    $args = array(
        'smallest'    => 18, 
        'default' => 18, 
        'largest'    => 18, 
        'unit' => 'px',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'format' => 'list',
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    return $args;
}
```

Somehow this messes up the widget HTML now. `<h2>` and the widget wrapper `<div>` are gone. Looking at the wp_tag_cloud function reference, I don't see how to pass any arguments to avoid this... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

Comment: With that filter, the `$args` includes the sidebar settings like `before_widget` - try `var_dump($args);`. So if you overwrite the entire array, you need to explicitly set the sidebar settings. Alternatively, override just those keys you wish to change their value - e.g. `$args['smallest'] = 18;`.

Comment: worked! if you post your answer I'll accept :P